# Specify Objective-C closure variable names from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm writing some Swift code that i'd like to use in Objective-C. The headers are all generated automatically but when using closures (that become blocks in objective-c), the variable names are missing.

For Example:

```
 @objc public func doSomething(success: (result: String) ->())
```

becomes

```
 -(void)doSomething:(NSString * _Nonnull)success;
```

Where i would have expected it to be:

```
 -(void)doSomething:(NSString * result)success;
```

Is this an Xcode bug or is there a way to specify what the variable should be named?

Comment: did you check https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25 ?

Comment: and please, finish your swift func doSomething definition ....

Comment: what do you mean finish the function? i.e. add brackets?

Comment: Also, the doc you referenced is for going Objective-C -> Swift not the other way around

Comment: no, no! function and closure in Swift has the same type!! so i recommend you to use function, and check how you will see it in Objective C. closure is like anonymous function in Swift

Comment: Sorry, i'm a little confused...can you give a code example?

Answer (score 0):

function and closure in Swift are the same type, you can try something like

```
// what you have
func boo(mf: String->Void) { mf("alfa") }
boo { (str) -> Void in
    print(str)
} // "alfa"

// try this
func foo(str: String) { print(str + " beta") }
// and see the signature in Objective C
boo(foo)

/*
alfa
alfa beta
*/
```

Comment: The output for this is the same: - (void)boo:(void (^ __nonnull)(NSString * __nonnull))mf;